# Angular reactive forms and ControlValueAccessor, form value is always null

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

Hi am trying to implement ControlValueAccessor with reactive forms, but I always receive null value for the form on the parent component.
Am trying to use the child component in many places therefore I need it to be reusable and can be added to parent forms

Thanks for help
Child component

```
    import { ControlValueAccessor, FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, NG_VALIDATORS } from '@angular/forms';
import { Component, HostBinding, Input, OnDestroy, OnInit, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Ng4LoadingSpinnerService } from 'ng4-loading-spinner';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { startWith, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { cons } from 'src/app/services/helper.service';
export interface ImzaYetkilisi {
  ad: '';
  emp_no: '';
}
@Component({
  selector: 'app-imza-yetkilisi-v3',
  templateUrl: './imza-yetkilisi-v3.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./imza-yetkilisi-v3.component.css'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => ImzaYetkilisiV3Component),
      multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => ImzaYetkilisiV3Component),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})

export class ImzaYetkilisiV3Component implements OnInit, OnDestroy, ControlValueAccessor {
  imzaYetkilisiForm: FormGroup;
  filteredOptions = new Observable<any[]>();
  yetkiliListesi = [];
  imzaTuruList = [];
  @Input() maxImzaSayisi = 0;
  @Input() maxParafSayisi = 0;
  @Input() imzaZorunlu = false;
  @Input() parafZorunlu = false;
  @Input() yetkiliIds: {};
  @Input() parafciImzaci = false;
  @HostBinding('disabled') isDisabled: boolean;
  subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];
  get value(): ImzaYetkilisi {
    return this.imzaYetkilisiForm.value;
  }
  set value(value: ImzaYetkilisi) {
    this.imzaYetkilisiForm.setValue(value);
    this.onChange(value);
    this.onTouched();
  }
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private spinner: Ng4LoadingSpinnerService, private toastr: ToastrService,
    private http: HttpClient) {
    this.imzaYetkilisiForm = this.fb.group({
      ad: '',
      emp_no: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
    });
    this.subscriptions.push(
      this.imzaYetkilisiForm.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
        this.onChange(value);
        this.onTouched();
      })
    );
  }
  onChange: any = () => { };
  onTouched: any = (_: any) => { };

  writeValue(obj: any): void {

  }
  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }
  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    this.isDisabled = isDisabled;
  }
  validate(_: FormControl) {
    return this.imzaYetkilisiForm.valid ? null : { imzaci: { valid: false } };
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http.post(cons.baseUrl + 'xyz', this.yetkiliIds).toPromise()
    .then((result: any) => {
      //   console.log(result);
      this.yetkiliListesi = result;
      this.filteredOptions = this.imzaYetkilisiForm.controls.ad.valueChanges.pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(value => this._filter(value))
      );
    })
    .catch(error => {
      this.toastr.error('İmza yetkilileri çekilirken hata oluştur', 'Hata');
    }).finally(() => { this.spinner.hide(); });
  }


  getImzaciAd(emp_no) {
    return this.yetkiliListesi.find(y => y.EMP_NO === emp_no).AD;
  }
  imzaciChange(event) {
    const emp = this.yetkiliListesi.find(y => y.EMP_NO === event.option.value);
    this.imzaYetkilisiForm.patchValue({
      emp_no: event.option.value,
      ad: emp.AD,
      emp_cat: emp.CAT
    });
    this.filteredOptions = this.imzaYetkilisiForm.controls.ad.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(value => this._filter(value))
    );
    this.onChange(this.imzaYetkilisiForm.value);
    this.onTouched();
  }
  private _filter(value: string): string[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
    return this.yetkiliListesi.filter((option: any) => option.AD.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0);
  }
  onBlur() {
    this.onChange(this.imzaYetkilisiForm.value);
    this.onTouched();
  }
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscriptions.forEach(s => s.unsubscribe());
  }
}
```

the HTML for child component is ;

```
<div [formGroup]="imzaYetkilisiForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <mat-form-field class="col-sm-6">
      <mat-label>İmza Yetkilisi</mat-label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Yetkili Seçin" aria-label="Number" matInput formControlName="emp_no" id="empno"
        [matAutocomplete]="auto" #autoInput >
      <mat-autocomplete (optionSelected)="imzaciChange($event)" autoActiveFirstOption #auto="matAutocomplete"
        [displayWith]="getImzaciAd.bind(this)" >
        <mat-option *ngFor="let yetkili of filteredOptions |async" [value]="yetkili.EMP_NO">
          {{yetkili.AD}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the parent form is

```
    export class BankaOdemeTalimatModalComponent implements OnInit {
  imzaForm: FormGroup;
  imzaYekileri: any;
  constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal, public formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.imzaForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      imzaci: []
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.imzaYekileri = { ust_yonetim: true, direktor: true, personel: ['10488', '10484'] };

  }
  addImzaci() {
    console.log(this.imzaForm.value);
  }
```

and the HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="imzaForm" #f="ngForm"  (ngSubmit)="addImzaci()">
  <div class="modal-boy pt-1">
    <div class="largeContent">
      <app-imza-yetkilisi-v3 [yetkiliIds]="imzaYekileri" [maxImzaSayisi]="2" [imzaZorunlu]="true" [maxParafSayisi]="2"
        [parafZorunlu]="false" [parafciImzaci]="false" formControlName="imzaci">
      </app-imza-yetkilisi-v3>
    </div>
    <!-- <app-sup-list formControlName="testForm"></app-sup-list> -->
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 d-flex justify-content-end">
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success"  type="submit"
     >Ekle</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@MuhandY, In a Custom form control that implements ControlValueAccessor there're two important functions

1.-writeValue. This makes that when your formControl, becomes with a value, the control show the value (you can imaginate as a function that "initialize"), so you need makes some like

```
writeValue(obj: any): void {
  this.imzaYetkilisiForm.setValue(obj); //<--add this line
}
```

2.-onChange. well really the function you say in registerOnChnage, So you need makes some like

```
registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn; //<---is this.onChange
  }
```

So, each time we want to say to the "parent" that the value has changed you use

```
 this.onChange(value) //<--value the value your want "transmit"
```

You only need call to "this.Change" when you want to change the value "in parent". e.g. you has a formGroup and subscribe to valueChanges, only need call to this function in the subscription -it's not necesary make in blur or if you're changing another input that not change the value

Comment: Thank you, let me check it tomorrow and inform you, as I remember I did do you , suggestion but did not succeed. Let me try it

Comment: thanks again for your reply, the point here that did try your suggestion, but still getting null. do I have to hook registerOnChange function somewhere? its implemented as described in angular documents. onChange function is called in three places where form values are changed. But again the value is null. I found out that the parent form is not even informed that changes happened on the child form. this.imzaYetkilisiForm.valueChanges.subscribe do call onChange every time on change with the form new values.

Comment: here is the wrong code this.onChange(this.imzaYetkilisiForm.value);
    this.onTouched(); <----------------
  }. problem solved